# How to edit OnlyOffice Document Using MS Words?

Tags: onlyoffice

I've successfully integrate OnlyOffice Community Server with OnlyOffice Document Server. But how to allow editing document (docx, xlxs) using MS Words/Excel?

Or from different perspective, what kind of stacks should be use to allow document editing both using MS Words and OnlyOffice.

I want to avoid Alfresco is this solution. There's a long reason for this and I will tell if needed.

---

> Could you please describe the scenario when you use both OO Document
> Server and MS Office.

I have a webapps which has dropzone. When user drag a file into the dropzone, the file will be uploaded to OnlyOffice Community Server. From the dropzone, when user click on uploaded file, a context menu appear (Download, Delete, Edit With OnlyOffice Online, Edit With Desktop MS Office).

When user click Edit With OnlyOffice Online, a "shared link" will be generated by the OOCS API and redirect user to the editing page (which I believe is OnlyOffice Document Server editor).

So when user click Edit With Desktop MS Office, I want the document to be opened using his/her desktop MS Words/Excel and uploaded back to OOCS when user save from within MS Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONLYOFFICE Community Server allows you to open the documents using ONLYOFFICE Document Server or to download them to your client, where you are able to use Desktop Editors.
There are no connectors for any alternative document editing software at the moment. Could you please describe the scenario when you use both OO Document Server and MS Office.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I have edit my original post